# iOS (iPad) app crashing in simulator after loading

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6

Yesterday, my app ran fine on the simulator. I added a background image to the XIB, and tweaked the location some of my controls. Now when I try to run it, it crashes with:

> 2012-10-20 21:54:00.280 RIng It Up Scorer[580:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key autoBlue1Col.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1ca6012 0x10e3e7e 0x1d2efb1 0xb90711 0xb11ec8 0xb119b7 0xb3c428 0x2480cc 0x10f7663 0x1ca145a 0x246bcf 0x24898d 0x2aceb 0x2b002 0x29ed6 0x3b315 0x3c24b 0x2dcf8 0x1c01df9 0x1c01ad0 0x1c1bbf5 0x1c1b962 0x1c4cbb6 0x1c4bf44 0x1c4be1b 0x297da 0x2b65c 0x1ced 0x1c15)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

autoBlueCol1 is an instance of a subclass of uiTextField. I have 4 textfields of the class, and the one it crashes on should be the 3rd one it creates.

The subclass is:

```
#import "SPRalphaTextField.h"

@implementation SPRalphaTextField

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

   [super awakeFromNib];

    self.delegate = self;


}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if([string length]==0)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([[textField text] length] + [string length] - range.length > 1)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    /*  limit to only ABC characters  */
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcABC"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

This should be a simple program. I only have one view. I have 3 different subclasses, but those are all textboxes. I'm sure I probably need to add more code to this. Just let me know what would help, and I'll add it.

Comment: I should add that the XIB file does have AutoBlue1Col listed as the right class. (that seems to be a common reason for this error).

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, I deleted the referencing outlet for autoBlue1Col, and it starting crashing on the next textfield instead which is of a different class.  I do have 60 textfields in this xib. Is it possible that I'm overloading it?

Comment: More experimentation. I deleted 4 textfields around AutoBlue1Col, and then it crashes on a segmented control that doesn't have a custom class. I'm thinking that there's something corrupt in my xib file.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out **this** problem. I set the main interface in the properties. I did that because the app was hanging on the loading screen, so I thought that was that issue. I took it back out, and am back to being stuck on loading... which is a different issue (maybe).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that I created this problem by trying to solve a different one. I set the main interface in the application properties. I did that because the app was hanging on the loading screen, so I thought that was that issue. I'm going to create a new question with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set the value of an undefined key somewhere. Here is the error:

**[setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key autoBlue1Col**

Are you setting the value of autoBlue1Col anywhere in your app? If so make sure the name of the key is correct or that it exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. I just check to see what it contains. I searched my code for all instances where I use it to make sure that there wasn't some weird typo causing it. None that I can find.